# Is it possible to force a apple wireless keyboard to disconnect, from the keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a single keyboard that is paired to multiple iOS devices.   Once it's actively connected to one of them, it seems the only way to get it to be willing to connect with another is to turn off bluetooth on the current device.   Is there a magic key chord or something that will kick the current device off so a new one can connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I do not believe the Apple Keyboard has a hotkey to do multi-device switching, but Logitech does have a couple with switching capability. Logitech Bluetooth Multi-Device Keyboard (K480) and the Easy Switch Keyboard (K811).